# Could not find or load main class (classname) in Scala Intellij

Tags: scala, intellij-idea

I am learning Scala and while writing some programs. I am getting following

```
> error:could not find or load main class Animal
```

I am getting this error even if I delete the class or rename the class.
I am creating this program inside `src->main->scala->Animal(package)->Animal(class)`.

I tried to search for solutions on Google and on this site but that did not help me. Please let  me know what I am missing. I am running this program on `Intellij`.

I am getting this error for other programs as well.

```
package Animal

class Animal {
def a:Int = 10
  println(a)
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps you have previously written an application whose `main` method was in the `Animal` object. Either delete the run configuration that points to this class or make `Animal` an application by making it an `object` with a `main` method, e.g.:

```
package Animal

object Animal {

  def a: Int = 10

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit =
    println(a)

}
```

You can also use the `App` trait and skip the definition of the `main` method, than you could edit your code as follows.

```
package Animal

object Animal extends App {

  def a: Int = 10

  println(a)

}
```

Comment: Thank you so much. Both of your solutions worked. However, I am not able to understand how can I change Run configuration to make it work if I want to use the class. In my Run configuration, I have class name as 'Animal' and rest of the things are normal. I might have used main method previously so how can I dissociate or delete the main method from this class in Run configuration. I also tried deleting existing class few times and then tried creating a new module but none worked when I use classes. However, your other solutions work perfectly. Thanks again

Comment: I believe the official documentation may help you far better of how I would: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/creating-and-editing-run-debug-configurations.html Feel free to upvote my answer if you found it useful. :-)